# добавление цвета, при изменения числа

Tags: javascript, jquery

нужен js скрипт, при достижении определенной отметки например 5, у числа появляется красный цвет,( если число меньше 5 то  цифра остается  без цвета.)

[image: сам элемент выглядит вот так]

---

cell.style.color = 'red';

Дальше мои знания не в силах преодолеть этот жуткий путь 9(

Comment: Для начала нужно определиться с тем, как вдруг и почему эта цифра вдруг должна поменяться.

Comment: блин, дай пожалуйста свой вк или связь с тобой,  лично обсудить хочу.

Comment: Извините, но нет. За пределами so я не обсуждаю вопросы заданные на so. Не стоит полагаться на одного человека, лучше попробовать задать хороший вопрос -- чтобы на него мог ответить любой участник, а не только тот, что имеет доступ к приватной информации, полученной частным путём. Здесь делятся знаниями, именно это является помощью вам -- вы же хотите что-то обсуждать кулуарно. Не мой путь.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let number =+(document.getElementById("cell").innerText);
let cell = document.getElementById("cell");

if (number >= 5) {
  cell.style.color = "red"
}
```

```css
#cell {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<span id="cell">6</span>
```